# Curl works but React App throwing Cannot POST / error while using Axios and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to implement a simple form to send email. The error that I am getting is

**Cannot POST /**

I've used Create React App and the App.js looks like below:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import renderEmail from 'axios';
import MyEmail from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      data: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // Call our fetch function below once the component mounts
      this.callBackendAPI()
        .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
      // Fetches our GET route from the Express server
    callBackendAPI = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/express_backend');
      const body = await response.json();

      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw Error(body.message) 
      }
      return body;
    };


    handleSubmit(event){

      const messageHtml =  renderEmail(
        <MyEmail name={this.state.name}> {this.state.feedback}</MyEmail>
      );

              axios({
                  method: "POST", 
                  url:"http://localhost:3000/send", 
                  data: {
              name: this.state.name,
              email: this.state.email,
              messageHtml: messageHtml
                  }
              }).then((response)=>{
                  if (response.data.msg === 'success'){
                      alert("Email sent, awesome!"); 
                      this.resetForm()
                  }else if(response.data.msg === 'fail'){
                      alert("Oops, something went wrong. Try again")
                  }
              })
          }

          resetForm(){

            this.setState({feedback: ''});
        }

   render() {
    return (
      <form id="contact-form" method="POST">
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
        <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
</form>
    );
  }
} 

export default App;
```

The server.js look like the below:-

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const creds = require('./config'); 

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
 app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
}); 



    var transport = {
    host: 'host', // e.g. smtp.gmail.com
    //service: 'gmail',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'xxxxx',
      pass: 'xxxxx'
    },
    tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }   

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport)

  transporter.verify((error, success) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('All works fine, congratz!');
    }
  });

  app.use(express.json()); 

  app.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
    const name = req.body.name
    const email = req.body.email
    const message = req.body.messageHtml


    var mail = {
      from: name,
      to: 'abc@gmail.com',  
      subject: 'Contact form',

      html: message
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          msg: 'fail'
        })
      } else {
        res.json({
          msg: 'success'
        })
      }
    })
  });
```

I have checked with curl and the localhost:3000/send is working properly and returns success. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling CORS in your server so as to enable React interact with your back end server?

Comment: how do you do that in Express?

Comment: I have checked and ` app.post('/send', (req, res, next) => { ` is what is required by CORS as per the documentation related to Express and it is present in the code